# Vacuum effect in ansys

Tags: ansys, vacuum

May i define vacuum as a negative pressure in ansys? This boiler tested for vacuum of 1520mbar.

[image: diameter 200mm, length 700mm]

[image: diameter 200mm, length 2000mm]

Comment: If this is meshed in shell, you may change the direction of the pressure to make sure it's in the right direction. Knowing that, a vacuum is an external pressure from the environment applied on your vessel.

Comment: Thank you very much @Öskå
1. You mean i can model vacuum like that.
2. Vacuum pressure direction from inside to out of tank through normal of face.

Comment: I would say from Outside to Inside, since your inside is supposed to be in vacuum. It all depends on the signs of your applied pressure, and how your modeled your vessel.

Answer (score 1):

Vaccuum basically means there is no pressure in the inside, but there exists a pressure on the outside. If you are using SHELL elements, the normal to the face becomes extremely important in ANSYS. Select the shell body, if the outer face is coming out Green, then the normal face is the outside face. If the inner face is coming out Green, then the normal face is the inside face.

For the first case where normal face is outside, if you apply a + pressure, then the pressure will act inwards towards that shell body. This is the same as vaccuum inside, and atmospheric pressure outside of the vessel. However, for the second case where the inner face is the normal, then applying a - pressure will have the same effect i.e. vaccuum inside of the vessel and atmospheric pressure outside.